# Different pageIndex with different iPhone devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I have trouble with my jumpToPage logic with PageViewController. I implemented logic shown below and it works fine on iPhone 5S/6/6 Plus and iPads... But on iPhones 5C/5/4S and below my method won't execute because pageIndex is different... Here is my code for pageJump:

```
-(void)gotoPage:(int)index{


SinglePageViewController *viewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:index];

UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirection direction;
if(_curIndex <= index){
    direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward;
}
else
{
    direction = UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionReverse;
}


if(_curIndex < index)
{
    for (int i = 0; i <= index; i++)
    {
        if (i == index) {
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:direction
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndex:i]]
                                      direction:direction
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:nil];

        }
    }
}
else
{
    for (int i = _curIndex; i >= index; i--)
    {
        if (i == index) {
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[viewController]
                                      direction:direction
                                       animated:YES
                                     completion:nil];
        }
        else
        {
            [self.pageViewController setViewControllers:@[[self viewControllerAtIndex:i]]
                                      direction:direction
                                       animated:NO
                                     completion:nil];

        }
    }
}

_curIndex = index;
```

}

Ok this logic works... Here is the method that check current pageIndex and calls this gotoPage method:

```
-(void)refreshPagesWith:(Articles *)article{
    NSUInteger pageIndex = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < self.pages.count; i ++) {
    Pages *page = [self.pages objectAtIndex:i];
    if (page.articleID == article.articleID) {
        pageIndex = i;
        break;
    }
}


if (pageIndex != -1) {
    NSLog(@"THEORY: Maybe pageIndex IS -1 on iPhone 5 and below!!!");
    [self gotoPage:pageIndex];
}
```

Ok here is the problem... On iPhone 5S/6/6Plus pageIndex is NOT -1 and the method get executed successfully and everything works... But for some reason, on iPhone 5C and below, pageIndex is always -1 and method won't execute... If i try to fore [self gotoPage:pageIndex]; app crashes... Can anyone help me change my logic somehow?!? Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok it seems that i resolved this problem of mine by myself, I just want if some1 who comes with same problem to know what i did...

For some reason, this line of code: `if (page.articleID == article.articleID)` do not compare objects in iPhone 5/4S simulator... I simply changed to `if ([page.articleID isEqual: article.articleID])` and now it works on all devices...

Note that `==` compares pointers, while `isEqual:` compares objects... I hope in future this answer will help everyone who encounter the same problem.